# how to convert proto Builder to java Constructor?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I want to convert proto deserialized Builder into java Constructor, which needs to deal with the wrappers class. When it encounters no assignment, it changes to NULL.

1.Use reflection（problem：poor reflection performance） https://github.com/singgel/protobuf-converter
2.Use constructors one by one set（problem：too much repetitive coding）

eg: proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
option java_outer_classname = "PeopleProto";

message People {
    int32 personId = 1;
    string personName = 2;
    google.protobuf.StringValue sex = 3;
    repeated string address = 4;
}
```

java

```
public class People {

    private int personId;

    private String personName;

    private String sex;

    List<String> address;

    ...
}

byte[] bb = ...;
People people = InterClassName.parseFrom(bb);
```

Comment: You want to inject a constructor in the proto --> Java source code generation?

Comment: Thinks,but I just to say the opposite, I want to convert the binary stream of protobuf into a custom JAVA class.  like this :byte[] bb = ...;
People people = InterClassName.parseFrom(bb);